# What version of Tomcat is TomEE 1.6 based on?

Tags: jakarta-ee, tomcat7, apache-tomee

We want to upgrade from Tomcat 7.0.52 to [TomEE 1.6 Plus](https://tomee.apache.org/downloads.html). What version of **Tomcat 7** is **TomEE** based on? Tomcat 7.0.50 fixes an DoS vulnerability (**CVE-2014-0050**) as mentioned [here](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/changelog.html).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is logged at startup but thats 7.0.47. Trunk is up to date and stable enough for prod btw